# Memory logic array blocks VS M20K

Tags: fpga, memory, intel-fpga

I am looking at the Altera [Stratix V](http://www.altera.co.uk/devices/fpga/stratix-fpgas/stratix-v/overview/stxv-overview.html) overview `Table 1`. In it, they distinguish two types of memories:

1. M20K memory blocks
2. Memory logic array blocks (MLAB)

What are the differences between the two types of memories?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Basically, the M20K blocks are dedicated 20Kb RAMs that you can use for making memories on the scale of KB.  The memory logic array blocks are logic resources which can be used either for logic or for small (less than 1 KB) memories.  Basically, the memory logic array blocks are how you use LUTs as RAM.